# Pickadate Clear/Close Button not closing picker in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, internet-explorer-9, pickadate

I’m having a problem with Pickadate & Pickatime on a site setup using Foundation,
the client has just noticed an issue with the Clear and Close buttons not closing the Pickadate pop-up in IE9,
which is making it impossible for IE9 users to complete the form.

This seems to be an intermittent problem,
it looks like the Clear button will work the first time,
but if you try and do this a few times in the same field you get the same issue.

The Close button was working for me in my tests in IE9 which would be a get out for users,
but sadly the client has come back to me saying that in their tests in IE9 (running on Citrix),
the Close button is not closing the Pickadate either which is making the form unusable again.

Here is the link to my demo:
http://my-allianz-fa-02.designchief.ie/claim-notification.html

The sequence is:

1. scroll down to "Please select a claim option" dropdown
2. select Accident/Incident option
3. In the Accident Details fieldset you will find the "Date of Accident" Pickadate field (Pickatime also used in the field next to this one)

Everything works as expected apart from IE9 where you can select a date ok, but when you re-enter the field and try to Clear the info, the Pickadate flickers (disappears and then reappears) and then cannot be closed.

The site was built using Zurb Foundation 4.3.2, Pickadate 3.5.6 (latest version) and is using jQuery 1.10.2.

This issue is not present in the Pickadate demo - http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/
which makes me think that something in the Foundation JS, or in the setup is causing the issue?

But, I have not found anything online that relates to this specific issue so I am reaching out in the hope that someone recognises the problem.
If the issue cannot be resolved then maybe you could suggest a solution using a new plugin but the preferred option would be to use the Pickadate solution as it suits the needs of the site better.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to revert to 3.5.4 version, and clear and close button are working as expected. You can download that version from:

https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/releases

Comment: Hi Antonio, many thanks for your suggestion, I tried version 3.5.4 but I was still having the same issues. Picking a date the first time is fine, but then if you try and select the date field again, and use any of the buttons, eg. Today, Clear, Close then the Pickadate will not close for me.

Comment: hm, strange, for me it works OK, it's public now http://www.heta-asset-resolution.hr/rezultati-pretrage.aspx?AuctionsSearch=1 look at field "Datum dražbe". Do you have some javascript errors in console ?

Comment: sorry I overlooked IE9 part :(, we have luxury to not support that piece of shit browser, so I didn't test this in IE9